# error on Decryption: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, byte, des

Here it is program for encryption and Decryption using DES. program is working when passing the output of encryption directly for decryption. but when taking input from user in string to decrypt, it showing this exception. how to pass cipher string in bytes so it becomes compatible for decryption?

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
public class DESEncryptionDecryption {

private static Cipher encryptCipher;
private static Cipher decryptCipher;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
try {

String desKey = "0123456789abcdef"; // value from user
byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
System.out.println(keyBytes);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyBytes));

encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encryptedData = encryptData("Confidential data"); //String from user

String s=encryptedData.toString();//String input to decrypt From user
byte[] bb=s.getBytes();

decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
decryptData(bb); //Exception

}catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }}
//method for encryption
private static byte[] encryptData(String data)
       throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      System.out.println("Data Before Encryption :" + data);
      byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
      byte[] encryptedData = encryptCipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
      System.out.println("Encryted Data: " + encryptedData);

      return encryptedData;
     }

//method for decryption

private static void decryptData(byte[] data)
throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
byte[] textDecrypted = decryptCipher.doFinal(data); //Exception trigered here
System.out.println("Decryted Data: " + new String(textDecrypted));
}}
```

Comment: Don't call `toString()` on a byte array. That doesn't do what you think it does. It's not even clear why you're using `s` at all, given that you've already *got* the bytes...

Comment: Can you put the imports in please, and everything else that's required so we can just copy and paste the code, compile and run it?

Comment: @jon assume s is the string entered by user. user can enter it only in string. ok i am giving code to compile.

Comment: Then they should be using base64, and you should decode that base64 to get the encrypted binary data. Encrypted data is *not* text, and shouldn't be *treated* as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't easily tell whether this is *all* that's wrong, but this is definitely wrong:

```
byte[] encryptedData = encryptData("Confidential data"); //String from user
String s=encryptedData.toString();//String input to decrypt From user
byte[] bb=s.getBytes();
```

Just decrypt `encryptedData` instead of of `bb`. Your `s` value is basically useless, because you've called `toString()` on a `byte[]`, which won't give you what you're apparently expecting. The value of `s` will be something like `"[B@15db9742"` because arrays don't override `toString()` in Java.

If you really want to turn arbitrary binary data (such as the result of encryption) into text, use [base64](http://iharder.net/base64) instead. Encode the result of encryption using base64 to get a string, and then later base64-decode it from the string to a byte array, then decrypt that byte array.

Oh, and I'd strongly recommend against using `String(byte[])` or `String.getBytes()` too - always use the overloads which take a character encoding instead.

Comment: How to use base64? i basically need to send encrypted data to a remote user in text format. the remote user have to decrypt the cipher. which he will enter in string format. so program need to convert in compatible format to decrypt.

Comment: @nitinkt: Well did you follow the link, or do a web search? Stack Overflow is great for helping people, but you do need to put in a bit of effort yourself.

Comment: yes, i have searched more then 3 hrs for this. in stack OverFlow and in google too. but not able to understand.

Comment: @nitinkt: I only posted my answer 32 minutes ago, so unless you already knew you were meant to be using base64 and didn't bother to mention it, I doubt very much that you've been searching for 3 hours on how to use base64. Again, did you follow my link? (It's to a page with a library which is *very* easy to use. Call `Base64.encodeBytes(String)` and `Base64.decode(byte[])`....

Comment: your link for base64 worked. i have edited these lines as, `String s=Base64.encode(encryptedData);
   byte[] bb=Base64.decode(s);`

Comment: i did not searched base64. i thought, the problem is occurring because of some crypto classes. means i was searching in wrong direction